# Question on Simulation based security proof for Oblivious Transfer (OT) against semi-honest adversaries

Tags: provable-security, oblivious-transfer, semantic-security, hard-core-predicate, simulation

I'm currently reading this [How To Simulate It – A Tutorial on the Simulation Proof Technique](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf).

On p. 10, there is a proof using simulation for 1/2-OT, against semi-honest adversaries. Briefly, the player $P_1$ holds the messages $b_0$, $b_1$ and the player $P_2$ hold the choice bit $σ$. Since $P_1$ has no output, it creates a simulator (p.11 bottom - p.12 middle) that simulates the $P_1$'s view. For $P_2$ it creates again a simulator (see p.12 bottom - p.14 middle) but while simulating the view it cannot output exactly $B(α,x_{1-σ}) \oplus b_{1-σ}$ so it just outputs B(α,x_{1-σ}). Then it proves that the distributions of the last two terms are computationally indistinguishable. It assumes that there is a distinguisher $D$ (see p. 13 middle - p. 14 middle) and that given $D$ an efficient algorithm $A$ can be created that can break find the pre-image of $B$ (which is a hardcore predicate) with negligible probability.

Question :
Based on the following definitions.
On p.13 it describes that assumed distinguisher $D$ as follows :

> Assume by contradiction that there exists a non-uniform
> probabilistic polynomial time distinguisher $D$, a polynomial $p(·)$ and an infinite series of tuples $(σ, b_σ, n)$ such that $$Pr[D(σ, r_0, r_1; α,(B(α,
> x_σ) \oplus b_σ, B(α, x_{1−σ}))) = 1] − Pr[D(σ, r_0, r_1; α,(B(α, x_σ) \oplus b_σ, B(α,
> x_{1−σ}) \oplus 1)) = 1] ≥ \dfrac{1}{p(n)}$$ .

On p. 13 middle it describes algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ :

> Algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ is given $σ$, $b_σ$ on its advice tape, and receives $(1^n, α, r)$ for input. $\mathcal{A}$’s aim is to guess $B(α, f^{−1}_{α}(S(α; r))$. In order to do this, implicitly and without knowing its actual value, $\mathcal{A}$ sets $x_{1−σ} = f^{−1}_{α} (S(α; r))$ by setting $r_{1−σ} = r$ (from its input). Next, algorithm $\mathcal{A}$ chooses a random $r_σ$, and computes $x_σ = S(α; r_σ)$ and $β_σ = B(α, x_σ) \oplus b_σ$. Finally, $\mathcal{A}$ chooses a random $β_{1−σ}$, invokes $D$ on input $(σ, r_0, r_1; α,(β_σ, β_{1−σ}))$ and outputs $β_{1−σ}$ if $D$ outputs 1, and $1−β_1−σ$ otherwise. Observe that if $\mathcal{A}$ guesses $β_{1−σ}$ correctly then it invokes $D$ on $(σ, r_0, r_1; α,(B(α, x_σ) \oplus b_σ, B(α, x_{1−σ})))$, and otherwise it invokes $D$ on $(σ, r_0, r_1; α,(B(α, x_σ) \oplus b_σ, B(α, x_{1−σ}) \oplus 1))$. Thus, if
> D outputs 1, then $\mathcal{A}$ assumes that it guessed $β_{1−σ}$ correctly (since $D$
> outputs 1 with higher probability when given $B(α, x_{1−σ})$ than when given $B(α, x_{1−σ}) \oplus 1)$.

Why while $\mathcal{A}$ chooses a *random* $β_{1-σ}$, when it guesses incorrectly it is like $D$ is invoked with $(σ, r_0, r_1; α,(B(α, x_σ) \oplus b_σ, B(α, x_{1−σ}) \oplus 1))$? Why is $B(α, x_{1−σ}) \oplus 1)$ equivalent to a random $β_{1-σ}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why while $\mathcal{A}$ chooses a random $\beta_{1-\sigma}$ when it guesses incorrectly, it is lik $\mathcal{D}$ is invoked with $(\sigma, r_0, r_1;\alpha, (B(\alpha, x_\sigma)\oplus b_\sigma, B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma})\oplus 1))$?
>
> Why is $(\alpha,x_{1−\sigma})\oplus1)$ equivalent to a random $\beta_{1-\sigma}$?

During this part, we are proving the simulation security for the case of $b_{1-\sigma}=1$, the definition is as follows,
$$
\underbrace{\{(..., B(\alpha, x_\sigma)\oplus b_\sigma, B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma}))\}}_\text{ideal world}
\approx
\underbrace{\{(..., B(\alpha, x_\sigma)\oplus b_\sigma, B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma}))\oplus 1)\}}_\text{real world}
$$
Then prove by contradiction, we assume $\mathcal{D}$ could distinguish the above ensembles. Also,

> Without loss of generality, we assume that for infinitely many $n$'s, $\mathcal{D}$ outputs 1 with greater or equal probability when receiving $B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma})$ than when receiving  $B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma})\oplus 1$

During the simulation process, $\mathcal{A}$ generates $\beta_\sigma$ and a random $\beta_{1-\sigma}$ (not necessarily to be uniformly random), then feed $(\sigma, r_0, r_1; \alpha, (\beta_{\sigma}, \beta_{1-\sigma}))$ to the distinguisher $\mathcal{D}$. And if distinguisher outputs $1$, $\mathcal{A}$ outputs $\beta_{1-\sigma}$, and if distinguisher outputs $0$, $\mathcal{A}$ outputs $1-\beta_{1-\sigma}$.

With $\mathcal{A}$, we want to prove that:
$$
\underbrace{\{(..., B(\alpha, x_\sigma)\oplus b_\sigma, B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma}))\}}_\text{ideal world}
\approx
\underbrace{\{\mathcal{A}(...)\}}_\text{real world}
$$
Recall the definition of distinguisher $\mathcal{D}$,

- When $\mathcal{D}(\cdot)=1$, $\mathcal{A}$ believe that its somehow generated $\beta_{1-\sigma}$ is w.h.p. close to $B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma})$, therefore (in the real world) it outputs $\beta_{1-\sigma}$
- When $\mathcal{D}(\cdot)=0$, $\mathcal{A}$ believe that its somehow generated $\beta_{1-\sigma}$ is w.h.p. close to $B(\alpha, x_{1-\sigma})\oplus 1$, therefore (in the real world) it outputs $1-\beta_{1-\sigma}$